# Build and install several modules from an Android Studio gradle Task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a grade project in Android Studio that contains several modules; each module containing an Android application or service. The applications/modules have **no dependencies** on each other.

```
Project
- module1
- module2
- etc...
```

I would like to build and install all of the apps with the push of a button. Is there a way to create a **gradle task**, for the project, that will compile and install each of modules/apps? If not, what would be the best approach to build and deploy the applications together?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get all modules/projects to work with the following gradle task in the root project:

```
task _installEverything{
    subprojects { sp ->
        println("Building and Installing: " + sp.name)
        dependsOn(':' + sp.name + ':installDebug')
    }
}
```

The task 'installDebug' can be used to compile and install each application; this task needs to be called in a **Lazy dependsOn** because the task does not exist when the root projects build script is compiled. This way, the following tasks will be called:

```
:app1:installDebug
:app2:installDebug
etc...
```